# How to make superagent return a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, superagent

I've been learning Node/Javascript, using promises from the start (I don't know how to *not* use promises and often wonder how others get along without them).

So I sometimes need to "promisify" simple stuff like reading a file with `fs`:

```
var readFile = function(path) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            else { fulfill(data); }
        });
    });
};
```

And that's been working great.  Now I need to do the same with `superagent`, but the chaining style it uses has me stuck.

```
var request = require('superagent');
request.get(...).set(...).set(...).end(callback);  // stuck!
```

I'd like to replace the `end()` method (or ignore it and add a new method) with one that returns a promise.  Something like this...

```
var endQ = function() {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        this.end(function(err, res) {     // "this" is the problem!
            if (err) { reject(err); }
            else { fulfill(res); }
        });
    });
};

// then I could say this:
request.get(...).set(...).set(...).endQ().then(function(res) {
    // happiness
}).catch(function(err) {
    // sad about the error, but so happy about the promise!
});
```

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521833/javascript-add-method-to-object) has all kinds of advice about adding methods to objects, but it's hard to see what is definitive.  I was especially worried by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522017/294949).  Much of the advice centers around starting with the object's "class" and adding the function to `.prototype`.  Something like this....

```
// this part doesn't make sense
var requestInstance = new Request();   // no such thing in request as far as I know
requestInstance.prototype.endQ = endQ; // would be great, but no
```

See my problem?  I want the JS equivalent of "subclassing" the request "class" and adding a method, but since its a module, I need to treat the request class as more or less opaque.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-as-promised

Comment: thanks @Daniel_L, will check that out.  Just for leaning sake, is what I'm trying in the question doable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595449/how-promisifyall-works-or-what-are-the-requirements-for-it-work

Comment: Re *"this" is the problem!*: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all [superagent already supports promises](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/request-base.js#L60-L78):

```
request.get(...).set(...).set(...).then(response => {
    // handle it here
});
```

Note that unlike regular `then`, the `then` here isn't a promise then - it rather actually *invokes* the request and acts lazily.

Second, what you want to do is pretty simple:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(request.get(...)).endQ = function() { // get to prototype and define
  /* your code here */
};
```

Here is what superagent itself does:

```
exports.then = function then(resolve, reject) {
  if (!this._fullfilledPromise) {
    var self = this;
    this._fullfilledPromise = new Promise(function(innerResolve, innerReject){
      self.end(function(err, res){
        if (err) innerReject(err); else innerResolve(res);
      });
    });
  }
  return this._fullfilledPromise.then(resolve, reject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'm going to use the native promise that you suggest, but I'm confused a little by the `getPrototypeOf(request.get(...))`.  Wouldn't it be `getPrototypeOf(request)` ?  Otherwise, wouldn't I be getting the prototype of the result of invoking get?  Thanks again for all the help.