# knex transaction is not working with async await

Tags: javascript, mysql, transactions, knex.js

im workin with knex and node, when im trying to use transaction its not working and trhowing following error
`Unhandled rejection TypeError: container is not a function`,
i dont know why what happend, anyone know whats wrong with my syntax or knowing better syntax?

```js
  const insertData = async (tableName, data) => {
 try {
  return knex(tableName)
   .insert(data);
 
 } catch (err) {
  logger.error('error function insertData :global model', err);
  return false;
 }
};
  

const createAccount= async (dataAddress, dataAccount) => {
 let trx = knex.transaction();
 try {
  const insertDataAddress = await insertData('mdm_address_contact', dataAddress);
  await global.insertData('mdm_account1', Object.assign({ id_address: insertDataAddress[0] }, dataAccount));
  trx.commit();
  return true;
 } catch (err) {
  trx.rollback(err)
  logger.error('error in function create account, mdm address contact:model', err);
  return false;
 }
};
```

Comment: take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580674/get-knex-js-transactions-working-with-es7-async-await

Comment: i tried, it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

There were various errors in the code, something like this should work a bit better (this code too still looks horrible though):

```
const insertData = async (tableName, data) => {
  try {
    return await knex(tableName).insert(data);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('error function insertData :global model', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const createAccount = async (dataAddress, dataAccount) => {
  try {
    return await knex.tranasaction(async trx => {
      const insertDataAddress = await insertData('mdm_address_contact', dataAddress);
      await insertData('mdm_account1', Object.assign({ id_address: insertDataAddress[0] }, dataAccount));
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('error in function create account, mdm address contact:model', err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Comment: imma try it,,thanks for it, will confirm if its works or not :)