# Unable to catch knex transaction rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, knex.js, koa

I'm using knex transaction with async/await syntax as suggested in this question: [Get Knex.js transactions working with ES7 async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580674/get-knex-js-transactions-working-with-es7-async-await)

My problem is, that when transaction fails and trx callback is invoked, knex logs

> Unhandled rejection error: relation "some_table" doesn't exist // Example error which I used for testing

just under the same error logged by logger, so logs looks like that:

```
// Removed error stacks...

// Error logged by logger
2019-07-14T23:12:29.606Z [error]: error: insert into "tab1" ("col1", "col2", "col3") values ($1, $2, $3) returning "col3" - relation "tab1" does not exist

// Koa.js error from ctx.throw()
InternalServerError: Internal Server Error

// Error when invoking await trx.rollback(e)
Unhandled rejection error: relation "tab1" does not exist
```

What I want to achive is to call trx.rollback(e) without throwing unhandled rejection error.

And the code causing this problem:

```
async function create (ctx) {
  const trx = await tools.promisify(knex.transaction.bind(knex))
  try {
    let [var1] = await trx('tab1').insert({...}).returning(['x', 'y'])

    // tab2 doesn't exist to trigger an error
    const [var2] = await trx('tab2').insert({...}).returning('z')

    await trx.commit()
  } catch (e) {
    await trx.rollback(e)
    logger.error(e)
    ctx.throw()
  }
}
```

Comment: Literally remove the line `ctx.throw()`

Comment: @James, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, removing `ctx.throw()` doesn't resolve issue.

Comment: Are you sure that there's a rollback to be done? I'm thinking that the transaction never committed b/c it threw an error before trx.commit().

Comment: @DovRine Yes, an error occurs before `trx.commit()`, but if I just skip `trx.rollback()` idle connections remains in PostgreSQL server.

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk: Connections, but not a transaction waiting to commit. Did the inserts happen? It doesn't seem like it. Maybe you need to get handles to the db connections and close them manually in the error-handler. Isn't there a trx.abort() or something? (Sorry, I haven't used knex in about 5 years.)

Comment: @DovRine No, inserts doesn't happen when error is throwed before `trx.commit()`. I also tried to remove `trx.rollback()` and `trx.commit()`, but then inserts are not performed. Maybe it's knex problem...

Comment: You don't need to rollback if the commits never happen. The issue now is releasing the resources that trx is using bc it will never complete.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems like they are recommending async transactions. This would eliminate your respurce errors bc knex manages them automatically. https://knexjs.org/#Transactions

Comment: I can't find an oppsite method to trx.start(),so I assume that it's supposed to bbe garbage collected normally. Maybe you can reassign trx to null or something to force gc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using transactions wrong... try this:

```
async function create (ctx) {
  try {
    const res = await knex.transaction(async trx => {
      let [var1] = await trx('tab1').insert({...}).returning(['x', 'y'])
      // tab2 doesn't exist to trigger an error
      const [var2] = await trx('tab2').insert({...}).returning('z')

      return [var1, var2];
    });
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e)
    ctx.throw()
  }
}
```

Also if you really want you can use latest knex 0.18 and `transactionProvider()`... it is found from knex docuementation... but in your case 1st way works even better and will be more robust that explicit commit.

Real answer to your question is that the line:

```
trx = await tools.promisify(knex.transaction.bind(knex))
```

doesn't bind any handlers to promise chain returned by `knex.transaction(trx => {...})` call and then when you call `.rollback(e)` that chain rejects and leaks that exception.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I modified my code and now errors are catched correctly.