# How to create promises from library

Tags: javascript, promise

I am confused on this one because every tutorial I have found so far assumes I can edit the library code, or that the library only has call backs or the call back as the last parameter.

The library I am using has every function set up like
`function(successCallBack(result), FailCallBack(error),options)`

So in each instance, I end up using code like

```
var options={stuff1:1, stuff2:2};

doStuff(success,failure,options);

function success(result){
    //handle, usually with another call to a similar function, chaining callbacks together
};

function failure(error){
     //handle error
};
```

How do I convert these into promises when I only have control of the call, and the success and failures?

Also, as a bonus, the chains are accessing variables outside them.

```
var options={stuff1:1, stuff2:2};

doStuff(success,failure,options);

function success(result){
    var options2={stuff1:1, stuff2:2};
    doStuff2(function(result2){
                processStuff(result1, result2);
            },function(error){
                 //handle error
            },options2)
};

function failure(error){
     //handle error
};

function processSuff(result1,result2){
    //do things to results
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Working version of a "promisify" function that can be used to create a new function that "wraps" an existing function converting a traditional callback interface to a function returning a promise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391419/trying-to-understand-how-promisification-works-with-bluebird/26391516#26391516.  Also, the [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) has both `.promisify()` and `.promisifyAll()`.

Comment: These assume you have a function with a typical async calling convention of single callback as last argument.  When you do not have that, you will have to adapt these to fit your calling convention.

Comment: I have bluebird but I don't yet know how to use it properly

Comment: Because your functions that take two callbacks and first and second arguments are non-standard for async calling, you can't use Bluebird right out of the box to promisify.  You will have to create your own promise-returning wrapper for each function you want to use with promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah thank you, that explains my confusion a bit better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following function. It accepts a function to promisify and options, and returns promise:

```
let promisify = (fn, opts) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(resolve, reject, opts);
  });
}
```

It could be used as follows:

```
promisify(doStuff, options)
  .then(data => console.log('Success call', data))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
```

Comment: in the `  .then(() => /* Success call*/)`  how does it get the results?  do I put the success(result) function call there?

Comment: Updated the code, `then` callback will accept the parameter which will be passed to the original `success` function.

Comment: Thank you.  It will take me a little bit of time to test implement this, but this looks really good, if confusing to a javascript rookie like me.  Can I use this to fix the variable scope piece where the last item in the chain reads the results of each chain?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than call promisify every time you want to use your function, you can wrap it once and get a new function that you can just use as needed.  The new function will return a promise and resolve/reject instead of the success and fail callbacks.  This particular version of promisify is specifically coded for the calling convention you show of `fn(successCallback, errorCallback, options)`.  If you have other functions with different calling conventions, then you can create a different promisify version for them:

```
// return a promisified function replacement for this specific
//    calling convention: fn(successCallback, errorCallback, options)
function promisify1(fn) {
    return function(options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(resolve, reject, options);
        });
    }
}
```

So, then you would use this like this:

```
// do this once, somewhere near where doStuff is imported
let doStuffPromise = promisify1(doStuff);

// then, anytime you would normally use doStuff(), you can just use
//    doStuffPromise() instead

doStuffPromise(options).then(results => {
    // process results here
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can "promisify" a given function of set of functions just once in your project and then just use the new promisified versions.

---

Suppose you imported an object that had a whole bunch of these types of interfaces on it.  You could then make yourself a `promisifyObj()` function that would make a promisified interface for all the functions on the object.

```
// a "Promise" version of every method on this object
function promisifyAll(obj) {
    let props = Object.keys(obj);
    props.forEach(propName => {
        // only do this for properties that are functions
        let fn = obj[propName];
        if (typeof fn === "function") {
            obj[propName + "Promise"] = promisify1(fn);
        }
    });
}
```

So, if you had an object named `myModule` that had all these methods with this non-promise interface on it, you could promisify that module in one step:

```
promisifyAll(myModule);
```

And, then you could use any method from that object by just adding the "Promise" suffix to the method name:

```
myModule.someMethodPromise(options).then(results => {
    // process results here
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```