# Node.js odd number count error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Created a file name big.file and stored values

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fscreateWriteStream('./big.file');

for(let i=0; i<= 2; i++) {
  file.write('1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n');
}
file.end()
```

I read the file and I tried to find the count of oddnumbers

```
const file2 = fs.readFile('./big.file','utf8', (err,lines) = {
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log(lines);
 const numbers = lines.map(Number);
 const oddNumbers = numbers.filte(n => n%2 ===1);
 console.log('odd number count:', oddNumbers.length);
});
```

This is my output:

```
C:\projects\rough>node index.js
1
2
3

C:\projects\rough\index.js:13
        const numbers = lines.map(Number);
                              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines` is a string, not an array, because of that you're getting this error. `String` doesn't have `map()` method.
To get an array you need to split data by `\n` (newline) character.

```
fs.readFile('./big.file', 'utf8', (err, data) = {
  if (err) throw err;
  const lines = data.split('\n');
  console.log(lines);
  const numbers = lines.map(Number);
  const oddNumbers = numbers.filter(n => n%2 ===1);
  console.log('Odd numbers count:', oddNumbers.length);
});
```

Comment: nice, you should set this question answered for him @daneilcliff

Comment: How could I do the same thing using promises @alexmac

Comment: You need to _promisify_ `fs#readFile` method, it's possible to do using such libraries as `bluebird` or `Q`, or you can do _promisification_ manually, please check this answer to get more info: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494127/how-to-create-promises-from-library/45494186#45494186](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494127/how-to-create-promises-from-library/45494186#45494186)

Comment: const file3 = fs.readFile('./big.file', 'utf8')
  .then(results => {
    var data = fs.readFile('/.big.file')
   const lines = data.split('\n');
    const numbers = lines.map(Number);
    const oddNumbers = numbers.filter(n => n%2 === 1);
    console.log('Odd numbers count:', oddNumbers.length);
  })
  .catch(console.error);

I tried this way,but I am sure its the wrong way for manual promisification.

Comment: You didn't promisification in provided code. Please create a new question, and I'll try to give an answer. And mark the current answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005981/node-js-promisifaction-error .I placed the question 

@alexmac